# Matching the option key for a list/carousel

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to match the option keys in a carousel/list to those of the following intents.

How do I go about adding it into fulfillment? Do I have to code the entire list and the responses? My coding skills are novice and I can't ascertain how to do this even from multiple examples I've dug up on here and on the DF documentation.

I've seen examples that include:

> const param = app.getContextArgument('actions_intent_OPTION','OPTION').value;

How would I implement that in DF? Where would I define param? In the followup intents?

Sorry, I am really lost. If anyone has an example on both the DF GUI, as well as the fulfillment side I think I could figure it out for myself. Just looking at strictly code with no reference to DF isn't enough for me unfortunately.

--

On a side note, why can't DF just take the user says from clicking the card and match it to the followup intent? Why is a webhook even needed? Or why couldn't the option key be pushed to an entity?

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: You may have this question tagged incorrectly.  Doesn't seem to be a node.js issue... thus it's easy for it go not be seen by the proper folks.  Is this Android you're working with, since you're using intents?  If so, change your tags to add "android" and "java".  Will get  more visibility that way.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey @dvsoukup it is part node.js coding, part working with Google's Dialogflow to reference the code.
https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/DialogflowApp/

Comment: I stand corrected then!  Thanks for the clarification.